# php Search using sessions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Can someone suggest some reading for database search operation using sessions or some other best practice. 
i have a scenario where the user search for events with different filters. i get them through ajax an display them. then the user can filter on current results. upon clicking a filter i get the new results from the back-end. Right i am sesnding the clicked filters in an array to back-end querying the database for every click . this is not an ideal approach. i heard sessions can help for storing search results thereby extracting it when applying new filters on the existing rsultset with out querying database .  Any suggestions?

I am usng Laravel and Mysql

Answer (score 1):

For best practices you should check the [MySQL](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-tutorial-excerpt-5.1-en.pdf)  and [Lavarel by phpacademy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfSjm-MwhNM) also can help you. Or choose some of the free books on [PHP](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#php). For more specific answers you can show some code you've done.